# Simply posting variables through GET in cURL

Tags: php, curl

so I'm trying to make a small API here. I'll be only sending some information via header (get params) and I'm not using any POST parameters.
Here's the code that I've written.

```
function sendSMS($message, $number)
{
  /*** Connection Params **/
  /*** Build the request parameters ***/
  $service="sms_api_call_receiver.php";
  $number="1212";
  $message="asas";
  $result = sendPost("https://www.domain.com/smsapp/" . $service . "?message=".urlencode($message)."&number=".$number);
  return $result;
}//function

function sendPost($Url)
{
   // Initialisation
   $ch=curl_init();
   // Set parameters
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
   // Return a variable instead of posting it directly
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   // Active the POST method
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1) ;
   // Request
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strRequest);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   // execute the connexion
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Close it
   //return curl_error($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

On the receiver file, I have this code :-

```
if(isset($_GET['message']))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return "12212";
}
```

But when I test, the output I get is :-

```
string '' (length=0)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Troubleshooting**
I tried to see if `curl_error` returned anything. But I could see nothing.
Any suggestions here would be helpful.

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)`, make sure those parameters are actually coming through at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is something wrong there? If `$_GET['message']` is set (in your test example it is) the script (sms_api_call_receiver.php) returns true and stops the execution.

Because it is HTTP request, and the response is empty, you'll get as result in the `sendSMS()` function string with 0 length.

Comment: Ok, so instead of return true if I return something like `return "ok"`. Will I get ok instead f a 0 length string?

Comment: Absolutely. Whatever you print there, will be passed back and returned by `sendSMS()`. The correct way to do it is `echo "ok";`.

Answer (score 1):

to get something as response in sendSMS you need to print in sms_api_call_receiver.php instead of using return